# Syntax error in javascript: missing )

Tags: javascript

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error

```
   var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET' 'http://webwizardservices.com/first-1.json');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
        console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
```

Answer (score 4):

Parameters in function calls like `.open()` must be separated by commas. Your function call lacks a comma.